# Remove a contextual filter programmatically

Tags: 7, views

Is there a way to programmatically remove a contextual filter from a view? I have a view where, at times, I want to display it without the contextual filter active. This is the code I tried.

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'some_view') {
    unset($view->args);
  }
}
```

I also tried the same code within `hook_views_pre_execute()`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a contextual filters just set the `$args` to empty array or unset the desired arguments `unset($args[0])` to remove the first argument an so on:
Here is an example to remove all contextual filters:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'some_view') {
    // Remove all filters.
    $args = [];
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. This removes the args being set, but doesn't actually remove the filter. Meaning if I go into the View and actually click Remove, I get a different (desired) result than just settings $args to an empty array. So I may need to just create separate views and display them conditionally in code, which is fine. I'll most likely accept this as the answer, though.